# Intel RAID Web Console 2 and ESXi 5

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, storage, web

I have two ESXi servers with Intel SRCSASBB8I RAID controller.
When those server have installed ESXi 4.1 I was able to manage RAID configuration of those server using Intel RAID Web Console 2 running on Windows 7 workstation. It was possible without the need to install ANY additional software or drivers on ESXi servers (although RWC2 worked only in an old version 6.71.0100 - newer versions won't find my servers)

Recently we have upgraded to ESXi 5. RAID controllers are recognized by ESXi (on Health page) but I'm unable to use RWC2 any more (in any version, the newest one too).

Can someone confirm following things:

1. Did RWC2 can at all work with SRCSASBB8I controller from ESXi 5?
2. If yes, did it requires to install any additional software on ESXi servers (drivers from Intel, LSI Provider, etc.)? (I could just install those drivers I see what happens, but want to avoid "try and error" approach on production servers)
3. Are there any other means to remotely manage my RAID configuration without interrupting my VMs running on those servers?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally:

**You are required to install software to get RWC2 on ESXi 5.**

Specifically:

- Some controllers work directly with vmware's management facilities, and report disk health etc. You can check this on the health tab (or whatever it's called in recent versions) on your console.

As for the Rest...

> If yes, did it requires to install any additional software on ESXi servers (drivers from Intel, LSI Provider, etc.)? (I could just install those drivers I see what happens, but want to avoid "try and error" approach on production servers)

Well, grab some old HW and test for yourself.

Comment: I must apologize for providing wrong information. My RAID controller is NOT recognized on health page. Well, I will try installing "SAS Hardware RAID Driver for ESXi 5" from Intel and will report here a success or failure :-)

Comment: I have installed an Intel driver "SAS Hardware RAID Driver for ESXi 5" which replaced original one. Server works fine, but my RAID controller still is not recognized neither by health page nor by  RWC2. 
BTW, how could I uninstall this driver and restore default one?

Comment: You need to RTFM.

Comment: Well, I have read the RTFM :-) and found confirmation, than I need to install vendor specific CIM Provider. However it appears that Intel do not offer such provider, but instead suggest (in mentioned earlier tips and tricks white paper) using LSI Provider (unfortunately this document did not mention my controller model). It appears that Intel RWC2 can be replaced with LSI Megaraid software. Indeed, when you try to install on Windows both of them, then one of this product is updates the other. This is very strange for me, becouse as I know Intel and LSI are two different companies.

Comment: Intel controllers are rebranded LSI controllers.

Comment: I didn't know! Did you know which LSI model is equivalent of Intel SRCSASBB8I? If I will use LSI CIM Provider, would it be better to use also LSI Megaraid software instead of RWC2 or this doesn't matter?

Comment: At last I have managed to get working MegaCli command (according to this post: http://communities.intel.com/message/146995) but could not find any "CIM Provider", neither for Intel SRCSASBB8I nor for LSI 8708EM2 (which appears to be an equivalent of Intel card). If someone find/have proper "CMI provider" for those controllers (based on 1078 RAID chip), please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

It appears as though you need ESXi host-side software to provide insight into the RAID controller's health and to allow it to be addressed by the Web Console 2 software.

See the **[VMware ESXi 5.0 Installation and RWC2 Tips and Tricks White Paper](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/cs-033313.htm)**.

However, it seems like there's a current defect that may impact authentication there, according to the [Intel support forums](http://communities.intel.com/message/197421).

Comment: I have already found those information, but they are not intended for my controller model (SRCSASBB8I).